# Asp.Net Webforms out of the box security

Tags: asp.net

Does anybody know of a simple explanation of the ASP.Net Forms security that is available with an ASP.WebForms or ASP.WebSite project out of the box. (VS2012)

I am looking for enough detail to learn quickly how it hangs together. e.g. The login button on login.aspx has a commandname property set to 'Login'. I assume somewhere there is a button click handler that uses this but where?

Where is the login data stored? There is nothing in the App_Data folder after the first run of the project where I successfully registered. There is supposed to be an SqlExpress file somewhere.

All the examples / tutorials I have seen to date seem to role their own login.aspx and use a standard button_click event handler. I can't see any actionable code in the OOTB project yet the thing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login functionality you are talking about is the login control that is part of the ASP.NET Membership provider.

Read [How to use ASP.NET Membership Login control with templates](http://www.howtoasp.net/asp-net-security-tutorials/how-to-use-asp-net-membership-login-control-with-templates/) for a tutorial on using this control.

There are several other ASP.NET Membership tutorials on that site.

Comment: Thanks Karl, that was the pointer I needed.